# Many freelancers have a personal website to showcase their skills and background. If you have one, did you guest post to promote your site?

Tags: freelance

Whether it be freelance writers, designers, video editors, or programmers, it's usual for them to have a website to attract leads, send to clients, and showcase their best work. However, a website comes with a lot of other work such as SEO and google ranking. I've heard that guest posting is a great way to expand online presence. Since I do have a website selling my services, I'm wondering if guest posting on relevant blogs will help with my website's SEO. I'm curious on your experiences on promoting your site!

Answer (score 0):

**Guest blogging SEO is a contentious topic.**

Guest posts are not inherently bad for SEO.

Guest posting (or guest blogging) is a marketing tactic that involves writing articles for other websites in order to promote your brand.

Guest posting can be good for SEO (and your wider marketing strategy) because it helps you build your brand profile. And, by extension, brand awareness.

When you showcase your expertise and partner with respected sites, you can establish credibility with readers, influencers, and Google.

That can lead to more social followers. New partnership opportunities. Higher rankings. And much more.

Plus, any links to your site can generate referral traffic.

Sharing your expertise with relevant audiences can help you:

- Build your personal profile
- Raise brand awareness
- Drive traffic to your site

Many marketers use guest posts to build links for SEO. (Links are like “votes of confidence” and can benefit Google rankings.)

However, An article on the [Google Search Central Blog](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2017/05/a-reminder-about-links-in-large-scale) states: “Google does not discourage [guest posts] in the cases when they inform users, educate another site's audience, or bring awareness to your cause or company.”

But guest articles can be bad for SEO.

Because Google may issue a “[Google penalty](https://www.semrush.com/kb/624-what-is-a-google-penalty)” (or “manual action”) against a site that engages in manipulative linking practices. This can lead to the site ranking lower in search results. Or being omitted from search results altogether.